# View doesnt render react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started working with React . i wrote a couple of codes already but this one just doesnt render in the View. can you help me out to figure what the problem is ?

```
var Card = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return
        (
        <div>
    <h3>Name Here</h3>
        </div>)
    }});



var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Card/>
            </div>
    )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
<Main/>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: What version of React are you using ? This is the old way to create components. You should now write a class that extends `Component`: `class Card extends Component {...}`. You can find more info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: @Ksyqo: The React top level API is _still_ a legitimate approach to creating React components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this

```
return
(
```

is the culprit :). It's returning simply without considering the rest.

Here is the working snippet.

```js
var Card = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return(
        <div>
    <h3>Name Here</h3>
        </div>)
    }});



var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Card/>
            </div>
    )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
<Main/>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```